# Prestashop - product page errors

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Hello stack overflow community.

I have a problem with product page in my prestashop backend office. I will show everything on the attached screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

For example: I try to add a new product:
- i cannot switch from standard product to the product with combinations
- categories to choose are not displaying correctly
- the brutto price is not counted properly
- there are no suppliers to choose from

Console logs while trying to add new product:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #form_step6_suppliers input[name="form[step6][default_supplier]"][value=Fashion Supplier]
at Function.Sizzle.error (main.bundle.js:49916)
at Sizzle.tokenize (main.bundle.js:50573)
at Sizzle.select (main.bundle.js:50994)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (main.bundle.js:49317)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (main.bundle.js:51240)
at new jQuery.fn.init (main.bundle.js:51357)
at jQuery (main.bundle.js:48523)
at supplierInputManage (form.js?1.7.0:446)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (form.js?1.7.0:465)
at main.bundle.js:48590
main.bundle.js:24426 Uncaught Error: No URL provided.
at new Dropzone (main.bundle.js:24426)
at Function.Dropzone.discover (main.bundle.js:25465)
at Dropzone._autoDiscoverFunction (main.bundle.js:25747)
at HTMLDocument.init (main.bundle.js:25716)
```

What I've already tried:
- a lot of searching over the Internet but i didn't found the solution (expect similar unsolved problems)
- overwriting admin folder to the original one
- overwriting js folder to the original one
- migrating prestashop to the server from different company
- changing php version to all, different ones
- temporary disabling all modules by moving them to the different directory

Do you have any ideas about how to fix that?
Looking forward for help.

Comment: That seems really strange, did you try to use the options to disable non prestashop modules and overrides? (Advanced Options > Performance)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to... delete Fashion Supplier? It is not exactly a solution but workaround, this js is missing `"` around the Supplier name, which shouldn't be a case in the first place but

The only way to solve this issue which is coming to my mind is to fix this issue directly in not compiled js code, though i don't have any issue with this on my installation of PrestaShop.